# Why is gcov creating Code Coverage data for STL Headers?

Tags: c++, g++, code-coverage, gcov

When I run gcov foo.cpp it not only generates the code coverage report for foo.cpp, but for all the STL headers used by foo.cpp.

Is there a way to prevent this?  It seems to ignore standard library headers like `<ctime>`.

**Edit**

Just ran across this post on the gcc mailing list:

[Re: gcc, gcov and STL](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2009-10/msg00050.html)

Comment: Yep, achieving 100% of stl coverage seems a colossal task, I doubt even STL developers have a test suite with 100% coverage ^^. This question is indeed very useful

Answer (score 7):

> -r --relative-only
>
> Only output information about source files with a relative pathname (after source prefix elision). Absolute paths are usually system header files and coverage of any inline functions therein is normally uninteresting.

Comment: thanks. basically that would ignore stuff included with `#include <header>` and track only stuff included with `#include "Myheader"`. The simplest solution to get rid of STL coverage ^^

Answer (score 5):

Any C++ header files with inline code will get coverage instrumentation when you compile and the results will be visible with gcov.  One useful flag is `gcov -long-file-names` (or just -l) which creates a unique .gcov output file for each header included by a given file.  The files have names like `foo.cpp##bar.h.gcov`.  This would make them easy for you to delete afterward with `rm \*\\#\\#\*.gcov` (careful with those backslashes!)

Another way you can detect these files is to look for the lines numbered 0 in the gcov output.  These have tagged information including 'Source:' with the full path to the original source file.

Comment: Maybe you had an old version, I do not see any file with a double # character in my results. However, there are binary files with .gcno and those match those filenames (you can see them using strings against those binary files.)

Comment: Great ! The '-l' solved me a lot of issues with inline & template functions.